# Exposing DataTransferObjects not Entities in WCF DataService

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, odata

I am currently trying to create a WCF DataService to Expose a large Set of Data.
The Data is displayed in a DevExpress Grid which has built in support for paging, sorting and querying on serverside.
This works absolutely fine if I expose the generated entities by entity framework.

However I would like to expose DataTransfer Objects which act as some sort of abstraction.
I can't really find some source of information on the web ...

Maybe some of you guys can get me going into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Create an `DTO` class that has a property named `Id` that has `[Key]` attribute.  Create a class that is inheriting `ODataController`, this is your controller. Put a method named `Get()` on it:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public virtual IQueryable<MyDto> Get()
    {
    }
```

In the method return your data with an `IQueryable`. After it call `EntitySet` on your DTO in your odata configuration.

Comment: If i understand correctly I would need to EF.Entities.ToList() -> convert this to Dtop as Queryable.
Or while retrieving from the database make a projection via select new Dto {...}. If I do this I would run into the problem, that the filter mechanism would nto work since the dto and the entity cannot be mapped.

Comment: Not forced to call `ToList()`. You can return output of your select like `EF.Entities.Select(x => new Dto{P1 = x.P1})`

Comment: As I said earlier, this would result in a problem with the filter. Since the Grid will filter on "Columns" e.g. Properties which don't exist or are named different within the Entity.